# The constructor being called isn't a const constructor. Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation. Flutter How to solve?

Tags: flutter, constructor, freezed, flutter2.0

I'm getting this error when I tried to build Object using Freezzed Package in Flutter
[image: Errors Screenshot]

[image]

If I tried to use some other datatypes instead of DateTime I'm not getting any errors

[image]

How to solve this? Thank you

*pubspec.yaml*

```
build_runner: ^2.0.4
freezed: ^0.14.2
json_serializable: ^4.1.3
```

*flutter version: 2.2.1*

Answer (score 0):

The error is causing because `DateTime.now()` can never be `const` it will change value of `DateTime.now()` whenever this class (`PracticalModel()`) gets instantiated.

Try removing `const` from your class

```
//...
// remove const from here.
factory PracticalModel({//...})
//...
```

Comment: I tried removing the const, now i'm getting some different error **Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.**